# What's wrong with my derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to differentiate the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}$.

I have $f'(x)=(\dfrac{x}{e^x-1})'=\dfrac{(e^x-1)(x)'-(x)(e^x-1)'}{(e^x-1)^2}=\dfrac{e^x-1-xe^x}{(e^x-1)^2}=-\dfrac{e^x(x-1)-1}{(e^x-1)^2}$

The answer of Wolfram is $-\dfrac{e^x(x-1)+1}{(e^x-1)^2}$

Comment: I have fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the last term is incorrect:

$$-\dfrac{e^x(x-1)\color{red}-1}{(e^x-1)^2}$$

That "$-$" operand must be a $+$, because you extracted the factor $-1$ from the enumerator and thus need to flip the sign of the constant.

Answer (score 1):

It's all correct until the last step where you make a silly mistake. Just before that step your answer is equivalent to Wolfram's.